Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" on path: DexPathList[***]at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
After updating the JDK version to 17 and the Gradle plugin to 8.5, my android application is crashing while creating an instance BouncyCastleProvider class with the above mentioned exception during runtime.
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

dependencies {
     implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.78.1"
}


Just a guess: removed as insecure

The class is still included in the used bc version, therefore it must be something else: https://javadoc.io/static/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15to18/1.78/org/bouncycastle/crypto/digests/SHA1Digest.html May be you use Prograd for shrinking and remove it this way from the generated DEX code?

@Robert with progaurd disabled, still issue persists
